# How to slice map of structs into a sub-set with the same keys?

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have a map of structs that holds several named values like this:

```cpp
struct MyData {
    MyType dataA;
    std::string dataB;
    int dataC;
  };

typedef std::pair<std::string, MyData> PairType;

std::map<PairType::first_type, PairType::second_type> dataMap;
```

This is defined in a header file of a compilation unit that calls a function from a library.
Because the library function does not know about my type definitions, I can't pass dataMap directly.
The function only actually needs the `dataA` struct member and already knows about `MyType`, so I could pass a `std::map<std::string, MyType>` instead.

Whats the most elegant way of cutting just the data I need from the map of structs and save it into a new map with the same keys but only the type and values from `dataA`?

Preferably for C++0x without usage of boost or other external libraries, but solutions for newer standards are also welcome for educational purposes.

I'm basically looking for an equivalent of Python's

```py
newDict = {key:value.dataA for (key,value) in oldDict.items()}
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the `dataB` members of your map keys are unique within the original map?  Is there a way to construct a `PairType` from just a string that can be used successfully to look up values in the original map?

Comment: What is the API of library? What it accepts? By "elegant" do you mean the simplest code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ranged based for loop to really easily make a copy.  That would look like

```
std::map<std::string, MyType> my_type_map;
for (const auto& pair : dataMap)
{
    my_type_map.emplace(pair.first, pair.second.dataA);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this as a single expression, you are going to need something like [`boost::transform_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/iterator/doc/html/iterator/specialized/transform.html), either by including that, or writing an iterator yourself.

Given a conversion function (or equivalent lambda)

```
std::pair<std::string, MyType> convert(PairType& pair){ 
    return { pair.first, pair.second.dataA }; 
};
```

You can declare `newDict` and populate it

```
/* can be const */ std::map<std::string, MyType> newDict { 
    boost::make_transform_iterator(oldDict.begin(), convert), 
    boost::make_transform_iterator(oldDict.end(), convert) 
};
```

Or you can use a [view](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html) [type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view)

```
auto newDict = boost::copy_range<std::map<std::string, MyType>>(oldDict | std::ranges::views::transform(convert));
```